# Reading from a processes stdout without placing it all in memory at once

Tags: process, rust

I am trying to capture the output from an external tool which is run in a separate process. I would like to do so in a non-blocking way as the output is larger than memory. I saw [How would you stream output from a Process in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550962/how-would-you-stream-output-from-a-process-in-rust) but I am not sure how to proceed. I have copied an example from [here](http://rustbyexample.com/std_misc/process/pipe.html) but this seems to capture output into a variable before proceeding. So far I have:

```
let path = "/Documents/Ruststuff/DB30_igh_badPE.bam";
let output = Command::new("samtools")
    .arg("view")
    .arg("-H")
    .arg(path)
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("failed {}", e));

let mut s = String::new();
match output.stdout.unwrap().read_to_string(&mut s) {
    Err(why) => panic!("{}", Error::description(&why)),
    Ok(_) => print!("{}", s),
}
```

Is it possible to loop over `stdout` from the child process instead of using the match? Something like:

```
for line in &output.stdout {}
```

Comment: Well, I was wondering if there was something as simple as capturing the output as it is generated. In python for example, you set a process running and you can use stdout=PIPE from the process and 'for line in sys.stdin' to capture the output into the parent script, if that makes sense...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need non-blocking IO for what you want. You can use [a buffered reader](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) to loop over the lines of input. This assumes that you always need a full line, and that a full line isn't too much data:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
};

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("yes")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Unable to spawn program");

    if let Some(stdout) = &mut child.stdout {
        let lines = BufReader::new(stdout).lines().enumerate().take(10);
        for (counter, line) in lines {
            println!("{}, {:?}", counter, line);
        }
    }
}
```

[`ChildStdout`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ChildStdout.html) implements `Read` for itself, but not for an immutable reference (`&ChildStdout`). Although we own the standard out, we don't want to consume it, so we need a reference of some kind. [`Read`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) *is* implemented for a mutable reference to any other type that is itself `Read`, so we switch to a mutable reference. Then `child` needs to be mutable as well.

Comment: This does not work anymore. When I run this example, the whole output is consumed at once.

Comment: @RainHunter I don't understand your comment. `yes` prints output forever, but this program exits (due to the the usage of `take`), which seems to indicate that it doesn't consume the **whole** input. If it did, this program would not exit.